# side by side eror,microsoft.VC80.MFC, version ="8.050608.0" could not be found

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, side-by-side, activation-context-api

I am trying to run OrCad capture but i got an error side by side and found out that the problem is :

> Activation context generation failed for
> "C:\OrCAD\OrCAD_16.6_Lite\tools\capture\Capture.exe". Dependent
> Assembly
> Microsoft.VC80.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50608.0"
> could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

but i cant find something in microsoft softwares to fix it .

Comment: The error diagnostic contains instructions on how to get more details (*"Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis."*). Please do so and supply the additional information. Besides, Stack Overflow is for programming problems, so this question is off-topic (see [help/on-topic]). Also please take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the 32-bit Visual C++ 2005 runtime. VC80 is Visual C++ 2005. IDK if it is still available...but this looks like it is probably it:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26347

Comment: Thank you this was the case with "Little Fighter 2" too, to be abe to run this on Windows 10.